# Как перезаписать определенную ячейку в CSV файле?

Tags: python, csv

Как перезаписать определенную ячейку в столбце в CSV файле?

Например, надо 5-й столбец и 6-я строка. В документации к модулю CSV не нашел такого примера.

Answer (score 2):

```
def update_csv_cell(address, new_value):

    filepath = '/home/idle/so/some.csv'
    dialect_params = dict(delimiter=';')
    col_num, row_num = address

    with open(filepath, 'r+b') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, **dialect_params)
        lines = []

        for current_line in reader:
            if reader.line_num == row_num:
                current_line[col_num-1] = new_value
            lines.append(current_line)

        csvfile.seek(0)
        csv.writer(csvfile, **dialect_params).writerows(lines)
        csvfile.truncate()


update_csv_cell(address=(5, 6), new_value='replaced')
```

*Выше приведён базовый код, без обработки ошибок.*

Плохих новостей больше, чем хороших.

**Хорошая:** модуль csv позволяет работать с обычными объектами-файлами, а значит вам доступны все методы таких объектов (см. seek, tell и т.п.)

**Плохая 1:** модуль csv считывает файл целиком, поэтому в ходе итерирования по строкам файла метод tell будет всегда будет возвращать позицию конца файла, поэтому иного простого решения, кроме как считать все данные, изменить их и пересохранить на горизонте нет.

**Плохая 2:** Подход с обращением к данным файла по позиции в документе ненадёжен, потому как, если со столбцами всё может быть относительно стабильно, то с рядом очень возможно и не угадать, испортив при этом данные.

Answer (score 2):

При работе с CSV (да и вообще при работе с данными) очень удобно и почти всегда более производительно пользоваться [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

Пример:

читаем / парсим CSV в Pandas Data Frame при помощи [read_csv()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) метода:

```
import pandas as pd

In [115]: df = pd.read_csv('c:/temp/example.csv', sep=',')

In [116]: df
Out[116]:
    A   B   C   D   E
0  54   9  74  73  59
1  34  20  66  81  14
2  89  33  87  98  41
3  74  78  19   4  25
4  30  12   7  52  29
5  33  45  39  73  81
6  49  28  48  69  99
```

меняем 6 строку и 5 столбец (внимание: в Pandas как и в Python нумерация начинается с нуля):

```
In [119]: df.ix[6-1, 5-1] += 1000

In [120]: df
Out[120]:
    A   B   C   D     E
0  54   9  74  73    59
1  34  20  66  81    14
2  89  33  87  98    41
3  74  78  19   4    25
4  30  12   7  52    29
5  33  45  39  73  1081
6  49  28  48  69    99
```

записываем обратно в CSV:

```
df.to_csv('c:/temp/example.csv', index=False)
```

Результат:

```
A,B,C,D,E
54,9,74,73,59
34,20,66,81,14
89,33,87,98,41
74,78,19,4,25
30,12,7,52,29
33,45,39,73,1081
49,28,48,69,99
```

Как легко и быстро сгенерировать тестовые данные (именно так был создан тестовый CSV):

```
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(7, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))
df.to_csv('c:/temp/example.csv', index=False)
```

или одной строкой:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(7, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE')).to_csv('c:/temp/example.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

- прочитать файл в список
- изменить элемент в списке
- записать список в файл.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте без модуля.
Если Вы умеете:

- Читать из файла;
- Разбивать на части строку имея разделитель;
- Писать в файл

то Вы сможете решить Вашу проблему не используя CSV.

- with open( .... as f
- str.split(тут ваш делимитер)
- f.write(...

Comment: А вот split использовать неправильно. Разделитель может находиться внутри строкового значения, заключённого в кавычки. Как и перевод строки, кстати.

Comment: Согласен про то что не совсем верно. Но если человек решит на коленке пусть даже не совсем верно. Ему уже дальше советы будут не нужны!

Comment: Не согласен. Ничего хорошего, если оно будет где-то по-тихому работать неправильно.

Comment: Получение знаний это процесс итеративный. Не возможно чем-то научиться не пробуя! Процесс пробования это означает допускание ошибок. Человек учится на ошибках! Можно часами читать теорию и искать супер-пупер правильный способ. А можно раз 5-6 налажать написав "на коленке" код, но получить конкретные знания как надо и как не надо! Я предлагал написать хоть как-то. Решить задачу хоть в каком-то виде!

Comment: Дело в том, что это не одно и то же, когда человек сам делает неправильно и когда ему намеренно советуют сделать неправильно. И даже не добавив никакой оговорки типа "в большинстве случаев подойдёт" или "Если файл не содержит ..., то". Предлагается конкретное решение. Причём для такого вопроса, что результат виден не будет и проверять, а правильно ли изменён каждый файл никто не станет. Т. е. ошибка обнаружится когда уже неверно перезаписана охапка файлов. Возможно, перезаписана безвозвратно. Хорошая ситуация?